# UILabel doesn't wordwrap if text end is smiley or emoji

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have a UILabel inside a vertical stackview, wordwrap, number of lines 0 etc (I have no problem displaying multilines text inside of it).

However if I end my text with a smiley like this :) the text will cut at a place that makes no sense since it is not the end of the first line and the remainder will not be displayed.

If the smiley is a true emoji then only the emoji will disappear if and only if the emoji is the only 'word' that goes in the next line.

Is there a workaround on this (proposed answer does not work) or should I file a radar?

String example :

```
Aujourd'hui j'ai telecharge mon application :)
```

Comment: By orphan you mean a single character? Doesn't work mate, my workaround is to use a \n before the emoji for the iphone 6 (which is the only size with the problem) but i would like to have a better grasp of what is really happening.

Comment: That's not the issue mate :) what is happening is that when the smiley or emoji should go to a newline and is the only thing in the sentence that goes into said newline, it will not be displayed at all by the system. And in the case of the smiley it will take some of the text with it and i end up with half the sentence not displayed. I just want the text to be displayed properly with the smiley/emoji on a newline if need to be.

Comment: Yup, nailed it. And it is a big issue since the label has every option set to adapt itself to whathever text I throw at it (i can put 30 lines of text with no problem), i don't get why it reacts differently with emojis/smileys. Seems like an issue with UIKit

Answer (score 0):

Try [decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409474-decomposedstringwithcanonicalmap), helped me with a similar problem.